# Playing a sound file when path is located in specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

When running a macro I would like to play a sound. However the sound will be determined based on conditions.   The sound file is located in cell A1.   Why can I not get the command to read the file path in the cell?  Any help would be appreciated.  (I realize this is very easy for some of you so please don't block me.)

```
' COMMUNICATION:  Play sound file located in cell a1
If Application.CanPlaySounds Then
    Call sndPlaySound32(Cells([a1]), 0)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sndPlaySound32 is an API function. So you have to declare it first. Put on top of your VBA module:

```
Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" Alias _
"sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, _
ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
```

Comment: confirmed this solution via this post: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx

Comment: Thanks,  I should have posted that I have this in my code.     I can get sound to play under the following conditions.                                                      ' COMMUNICATION:  "Play Sound"
       If Application.CanPlaySounds Then Call sndPlaySound32("C:\Users\jones.MAIL\Deskto\chime.wav", 0)
   End If

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing the value property try

```
Call sndPlaySound32(Cells([a1]).value, 0)
```

Comment: When I run this line of code, it says, Invalid procedure call or argument             Also.....how the heck do you guys get your code to look that way in your posts?                                                                                                               ' COMMUNICATION:  Play sound in cell A1
       If Application.CanPlaySounds Then
      Call sndPlaySound32(Cells([a1]).Value, 0)
              End If

Answer (score 0):

Your cell reference is wrong.

```
If Application.CanPlaySounds Then
    Call sndPlaySound32(Range("A1"), 0)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys.   Worked like a charm!    I had tried range earlier but I believe my brackets were causing the problem.